# What does adding butter to toffee do?

Tags: candy, toffee

Some recipes for toffee call for butter, some don't. I'd like to know please what adding butter does, and if I do add butter, will I still be able to make the stickjaw type toffee?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love this site, but there are some days I gotta avoid the candy tag #hungry. Eager for an answer to this question!

Answer (score 4):

Butter largely acts to prevent the crystallization of sugar in toffee. This leaves the toffee smooth and breakable.

> Fats in candy serve a similar purpose. Fatty ingredients such as
>   butter help interfere with crystallization—again, by getting in the
>   way of the sucrose molecules that are trying to lock together into
>   crystals. Toffee owes its smooth texture and easy breakability to an
>   absence of sugar crystals, thanks to a large amount of butter in the
>   mix.
>   [There's more about the role of ingredients in candies here.](http://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/candy/sugar.html)

You should still be able to make stickjaw (or, if not authentic stickjaw, at least a more sticky) toffee. The consistency of toffee has more to do with the temperature you bring the toffee to while cooking. [Here's a chart detailing the various stages of candy temperatures.](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Candy/candytemp.htm) For a sticky toffee you'd most likely want to bring your toffee to the soft-crack stage.

Here is a [recipe for authentic, old-fashioned, stickjaw toffee](http://sweetsciencesales.blogspot.com/2011/01/old-fashioned-stickjaw-toffee.html) but without butter.